# gson: Treat null as empty String

Tags: json, parsing, gson

I use [google-gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to serialize a Java map into a JSON string. It provides [a builder handles null values](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Null-Object-Support):

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
```

The problem is that the result is the string `null`, as in:

```
gson.toJson(categoriesMap));
{"111111111":null}
```

And the required result is:

```
{"111111111":""}
```

I can do a String-replace for `null` and `""`, but this is ugly and prone to errors. Is there a native gson support for adding a custom String instead of `null`?

Comment: Side note: `null` is a valid json value. See http://json.org/.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If this were your application type, you could register a type adapter. But Gson doesn't allow you to change the serialized form of strings or primitive types.

Your best bet is to change your Java objects. Or to loosen the restriction around nulls.

Comment: This seems to be [no more true](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/issues/detail?id=416) after OP's request.

Answer (score 45):

The above answer works okay for serialisation, but on deserialisation, if there is a field with null value, Gson will skip it and won't enter the deserialize method of the type adapter, therefore you need to register a TypeAdapterFactory and return type adapter in it.

```
Gson gson = GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapterFactory(new NullStringToEmptyAdapterFactory()).create();


public static class NullStringToEmptyAdapterFactory<T> implements TypeAdapterFactory {
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {

        Class<T> rawType = (Class<T>) type.getRawType();
        if (rawType != String.class) {
            return null;
        }
        return (TypeAdapter<T>) new StringAdapter();
    }
}

public static class StringAdapter extends TypeAdapter<String> {
    public String read(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
        if (reader.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
            reader.nextNull();
            return "";
        }
        return reader.nextString();
    }
    public void write(JsonWriter writer, String value) throws IOException {
        if (value == null) {
            writer.nullValue();
            return;
        }
        writer.value(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @oznus. From my understanding, Gson wont parse Json.Null values for keys. It will initialize the default value in the POJO class.So instead of adding a TypeAdapter, you can just initialize the variable in the default constructor. please correct me if I am wrong.

Please read this
https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

#NullObjectSupport

Comment: I did it just with Adapter part. AdapterFactory doesn't needed here.

Comment: It works for me where my result from server in json object is coming null and this above formula converts into blank string (" ").

Comment: Make note that the method used for the GsonBuilder is registerTypeAdapterFactory, not registerTypeAdapter, which you might already be using.

Comment: The `Gson` implementors doesn't seem to care to simplify their APIs. [Alessio's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20140419/2304737) answer is pretty straightforward.

Comment: This old but have many upvotes and wasn't working for me, after debugging, what worked for me was changing 'writer.nullValue()' to 'writer.value("")', to achieve the desired result of replacing null with empty string when serializing object to json.

Answer (score 27):

In the actual version of gson you can do that:

```
    Object instance = c.getConstructor().newInstance();
    GsonBuilder gb = new GsonBuilder(); 
    gb.serializeNulls();
    Gson gson = gb.create(); 
    String stringJson = gson.toJson(instance);
```

Comment: @avalon this return all field of that object i want only that field which null and exist in json so any solution for that

Answer (score 8):

Answer from [Google groups](https://groups.google.com/group/google-gson/browse_thread/thread/5b7797cea0a767a5)

I had the same situation. This sample helped me.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

public class StringConverter implements JsonSerializer<String>, 
    JsonDeserializer<String> { 
public JsonElement serialize(String src, Type typeOfSrc, 
    JsonSerializationContext context) { 
    if ( src == null ) { 
        return new JsonPrimitive(""); 
    } else { 
        return new JsonPrimitive(src.toString());
    }
} 
public String deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, 
    JsonDeserializationContext context) 
        throws JsonParseException { 
    return json.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsString(); 
} 
}
```

And uses:

```
GsonBuilder gb = new GsonBuilder(); 
gb.registerTypeAdapter(String.class, new StringConverter()); 
Gson gson = gb.create();
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no solution. I've [opened an issue at Gson's page](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/issues/detail?id=416); Hope it will get fixed on the next version.

Answer (score 1):

I had almost the same problem that I could solve.
I created an [issue](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1662) too.

I got this answer from [lyubomyr-shaydariv](https://github.com/lyubomyr-shaydariv):

> Gson does not touch missing values for, I guess, performance reasons and simplicitiy. You can easily implement a post-processing type adapter that would set the unaffected null-fields supposed to be optional to their default values

Based on the code snippet of the [original answer](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1662#issuecomment-600810455) I wrote a [sample project](https://github.com/fzoli/gson-bugreport/tree/f125278d103c9163bcd5e295d88b495eba955aa6) with [unit tests](https://github.com/fzoli/gson-bugreport/blob/f125278d103c9163bcd5e295d88b495eba955aa6/src/test/java/sample/SampleTest.java).