# Handling web services with null objects response

Tags: java, android, json, web-services

What is the best way to handle null objects in web service response for all services to replace them with "not available" in app.

ex. for the following response I am aiming to be able to replace all null string object with a string like "not available" :

```
"data": { "restaurant_id": 1, 
          "restaurant_name": "m&ms", 
          "logo": "", 
          "rate": null, 
          "price": 55, 
          "is_open": false, 
          "address": null, 
          "image": ""
        }
```

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/24252578/2750390

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Two way to approach null in parsing and it depends on the way of parsing.**

1) if you are parsing using POJO class then the best solution is when you retrieve value check in a getter method.
For Example: 
your converted POJO is like this

```
public class Data {

@SerializedName("restaurant_id")
@Expose
private Integer restaurantId;
@SerializedName("restaurant_name")
@Expose
private String restaurantName;
@SerializedName("logo")
@Expose
private String logo;
@SerializedName("rate")
@Expose
private String rate;
@SerializedName("price")
@Expose
private Integer price;
@SerializedName("is_open")
@Expose
private Boolean isOpen;
@SerializedName("address")
@Expose
private String address;
@SerializedName("image")
@Expose
private String image;

public Integer getRestaurantId() {
return restaurantId;
}

public void setRestaurantId(Integer restaurantId) {
this.restaurantId = restaurantId;
}

public String getRestaurantName() {
return restaurantName;
}

public void setRestaurantName(String restaurantName) {
this.restaurantName = restaurantName;
}

public String getLogo() {
return logo;
}

public void setLogo(String logo) {
this.logo = logo;
}

public String getRate() {
return getValue(rate);
}

public void setRate(String rate) {
this.rate = rate;
}

public Integer getPrice() {
return price;
}

public void setPrice(Integer price) {
this.price = price;
}

public Boolean getIsOpen() {
return isOpen;
}

public void setIsOpen(Boolean isOpen) {
this.isOpen = isOpen;
}

public String getAddress() {
return getValue(address);
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
this.address = address;
}

public String getImage() {
return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
this.image = image;
}

}
```

Now you can implement your own custom method to check whether string value is null or not? and if it is null then set default value which you want to pass. 
for an example, I have checked for the address and rate it is

like this

```
//It will return "Not Available" if value is null you can set your default value
public static String getValue(String value){
    return TextUtils.isEmpty(value)? "Not Available" : value  
}
//You can override it like this too.
public static String getValue(String value, String defaultValue){
    return TextUtils.isEmpty(value)? defaultValue : value  
}
```

2) if you are not using direct parsing and parsing JSON manually then

```
String jsonString = "Paste server response in json";

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);

            JSONObject dataJson = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");
            String address = dataJson.optString("address","Not Available");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this you can check wheather the value is null or empty inside your  Getter and setter  method

**Sample code**

```
public class POJO {
    @SerializedName("rate")
    @Expose
    String rate;

    @SerializedName("restaurant_name")
    @Expose
    String restaurant_name;

    @SerializedName("image")
    @Expose
    String image;

    @SerializedName("address")
    @Expose
    String address;

    public String getRate() {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(rate)) {
            return "not available";
        }
        return rate;
    }

    public void setRate(String rate) {
        this.rate = rate;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(address)) {
            return "not available";
        }
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }


    public String getRestaurant_name() {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(restaurant_name)) {
            return "not available";
        }

        return restaurant_name;
    }

    public void setRestaurant_name(String restaurant_name) {
        this.restaurant_name = restaurant_name;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(image)) {
            return "not available";
        }

        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

============================================

your if you want to pass manually than try this

```
if(jsonObject.has("rate"))
{
  if (jsonObject.isNull("rate"))
     {
       String rate = "not available";
     }else{
        String rate =jsonObject.getString("rate");;
     }
}
```

Comment: I need this to be generalized for the whole app.

Comment: AFAIK there is no generalized way for the whole appp either you have to check manually or modified you getter setter or better to you have change response from back end side @AhmedEsameddeen

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a tool like Jackson it will fail by default on unknown properties unless `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` on your model class is specified (or in object mapper's config).

Anyway, I'm just saying that Jackson is a common way of serializing / deserializing json in java nowadays and it will throw `400 Bad Request` by default on unknown props - maybe it's what you need?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSONObject` to parse it, and then just check for null and update it:

```
String jsonString = "..."; // Your JSON String

// Parse the JSON string into a JSONObject
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonString);

// Grab all the keys
Iterator<String> iter = obj.keys();

// Check each key
while (iter.hasNext()) {
  String key = iter.next();
  Object value = obj.get(key);

  // IF a key is null set it to "Not available"
  if (value == null) {
    obj.put(key, "Not available");
  }
}
```

Then you just use the `JSONObject` to populate your UI.