# GSON converting json to class object

Tags: java, android, json, gson

My json:

```
{
  "d": {
    "a": {
      "someId": null,
      "e": "8"
    },
    "p": {
      "m": "t"
    }
  }
}
```

I am using

```
gson.fromJson(ResourceUtils.getStringFromInputStream(inputStream), MyClass.class);
```

MyClass

```
{
public D d;
}

D {
public A a;
public P p;
}

A {
public String someId;
public String e;
}

P {
public String m;
}
```

But when I run it:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected STRING but was NULL at path $.someId
```

So basically I want to create an object from the json file in android app. I am using gson for that. But the null value isn't getting set properly.

Comment: What if you replace the null for d with ""

Comment: thats an empty sting, but I need a null object.

Comment: What does your my class look like

Comment: Edited the answer and added the class

Comment: And your A class?

Comment: Sorry @Turan Let me add the whole thing.

Comment: hope this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/a/24252578/4598342

Comment: Print your input string and see post what it looks like

Answer (score 1):

The Gson default behavior is to "ignore" the null properties. You can change this behavior calling the [serializeNulls](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#serializeNulls--):

> Configure Gson to serialize null fields. By default, Gson omits all
>   fields that are null during serialization.

Example:

```
public static void main (String args[])
    {
        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gsonBuilder.serializeNulls();
        Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
        String filename="path2/theJsonFile";
        try {
            JsonReader read= new JsonReader(new FileReader(filename));
            MyClass myclass= gson.fromJson(read, MyClass.class);
            System.out.println(gson.toJson(myclass));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

The output will be:

```
{"d":{"a":{"someId":null,"e":"8"},"p":{"m":"t"}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use from http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ 
to convert json to java class.

and convert Gson to json : `new Gson().tojson()`